# Logback configuration for MockMVC's logs when testing in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, mockmvc

I have trouble finding the right configuration that includes the console output generated by MockMvc (ie, *MockHttpServletRequest*, *MockHttpServletResponse* etc) in Logback's file and console appender.

Below the current console output I'm getting in IntelliJ.

```
2023-08-17T15:02:55.698+02:00  INFO 17720 --- [    Test worker] ish.user.UserApplicationMockedTests      : Started UserApplicationMockedTests in 5.549 seconds (process running for
8.227) 2023-08-17T15:02:55.943+02:00  INFO 17720 --- [    Test worker] ish.user.controller.UserController       : Getting user for ID: 100

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/v1.0/users/100
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = ish.user.controller.UserController
           Method = ish.user.controller.UserController#getUserById(long)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers", Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"id":100,"mail":"mitch.lee@hedberg.com","firstname":"Mitchell","lastname":"Hedberg"}
    Forwarded URL = null    Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
2023-08-17T15:02:56.158+02:00  INFO 17720 --- [    Test worker] ish.user.controller.UserController       : Getting user for ID: 1001
```

My **application.yaml** is configured as follows

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org.springframework.boot: INFO
    org.springframework.boot.test.*: TRACE
    org.springframework.test.web.servlet.*: TRACE
    ish.user.*: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.SQL: TRACE
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE
    org.hibernate.type: INFO
  config: classpath:logback-test.xml
```

I've added `org.springframework.boot.test.*` and `org.spring.framework.test.web.servlet.*` with logging level `TRACE`, but that didnt' help.

Here, also my **logback-test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener"/>

    <property name="APP" value="ish-user-svc"/>
    <!-- or in Java with: System.setProperty("LOG_DIR", "log"); -->
    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="log"/>
    <property name="LOG_LEVEL" value="TRACE"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>${LOG_LEVEL}</level>
        </filter>

        <file>${LOG_DIR}/test.${APP}.${LOG_LEVEL}.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/archived/test.${APP}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.${LOG_LEVEL}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>100MB</totalSizeCap>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_DEBUG"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```